# Idempotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question:

Let A be an idempotent matrix.

1. Show that I-A is idempotent
2. Show that I+A is nonsingular and (I+A)^(-1)  = I- ${1\over 2}$A

I solved 1:
  (I - A)^2

= (I - A)(I - A)

= I^2 - AI - AI + A^2

= I - 2A + A^2

= I - 2A + A since A is idempotent

= I - A.

So it is idempotent

However I don't know how to get startet with 2,

any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$(I + A)(I - (1/2)A)$$ 
$$= (I + A)I + (I + A)(-1/2)A $$
$$= (I + A) + (-(1/2) A - (1/2) A^2) $$
$$= (I + A) + (-(1/2) A - (1/2) A)$$ (Since A is idempotent) 
$$= (I + A) - A $$
$$= I$$

Hence, $(I + A)$ is nonsingular, with $(I + A)^{-1} = I - (1/2)(A)$ by the uniqueness of inverses.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but why do you start with multiplying them?

Comment: Because I know multiplying them will give me $I$

Comment: Okay thanks a lot :)

Comment: I can sense that you are not satisfied with it. You have any question you can ask me... I think you want to know whether I could have done $I+A$ is nonsingular without knowing the inverse. Is that your question?

Comment: No I honestly think I get it, but it was kind of hard to understand since to prove it, you have to use a given. You show that the given inverse works and it therefore is the inverse, if I explain it correctly.     And you really helped me well, thanks again

Comment: @Amaluena Just to let you know, I might not have been able to do it had the inverse not been given...that is what I waned to stress to you.